# Using enum declared outside class in another class

Tags: c#

I've been trying to use an enum declared outside of a class in a different class within the same namespace (as per the example below), but it gives me a

> The name 'StudentType' does not exist in the current context.

error.
What am I doing wrong?

File StudentManager.cs:

```
namespace Classroom.Members {

public enum StudentType {
    CHILL, 
    TROUBLEMAKER
}

public static class StudentManager
{
   public static void ManageStudents() {...};
}
}
```

File TeacherManager.cs:

```
namespace Classroom.Members {
public static class TeacherManager
{
    private static void LabelStudents(
        Dictionary<int, string> studentLabels) {
        Student = new Student(0);
        studentLabels[0] = StudentType.CHILL.ToString();

     };
 }
}
```

Even when adding "using Classroom.Members" to TeacherManager.cs it does not work.

Update:
Ok so as it turns out I cannot even access StudentManager.

Comment: Are `StudentManager.cs` and `TeacherManager.cs` part of the same project?

Comment: I believe so - they're in the same folder/directory, at least. Does that count? If not, how do I check that they are on the same project?

Comment: Do you see both files listed under the Project (it should have a C# in a rectangle icon next to its name) in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, I do. They do belong to the same project, then.

Comment: Side note, you don't need the semicolon `;` in the closing brace at the end of the method.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of Solution Explorer in Visual Studio, please?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot; the example above was an adaptation of another project I have, which I am not allowed to share. But I thank you for your continued effort toward our mutual understanding of the underlying issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It was an editor issue (Visual Studio **Code** June 2023 version 1.80, to be precise).
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80

Comment: "Visual Studio June 2023 version 1.80" - wtf? That version does not exist. Current is Visual Studio 17,7 - you mean Visual Studio CODE? That is NOT VISUAL STUDIO.

Comment: There is no such a thing as VS2023.

Comment: I did mean VS Code. Apologies.